# How to disable the Textbox's HTML encoding in ASP.Net?

Tags: asp.net, textbox, html-encode

I tried to display some text in Textbox(multiple lines) using ASP.NET. But I found that multi-line Textbox (textarea) is HTML encoded, meaning that when I want to display:

> a >= b; & c

It will be automatically converted to:

> a & gt;= b; & amp; c

which is NOT natural for people to read. So is there any way that I can disable this auto-HTML encoding behavior and just display it naturally in the Textbox?

Comment: Can't reproduce the error. When the text is displayed, it's displayed normally. Only the output HTML is encoded. Are you actually getting the encoded text displayed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are setting the text in the markup (.aspx), then what platon said is correct: .aspx is technically XML, so it has to conform to valid XML which means `>` is encoded as `&gt;`, etc.

If you are setting the text in code-behind, (for example, `textBox.Text = ""`) you could instead use an HtmlControls text area:

```
System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTextArea textBox = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTextArea();
textBox.Value = "a >= b; & c";
```

Comment: Yes I'm setting the text in code-behind. And using HtmlControls textarea solved my problem! Thanks Justin!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, you are talking about the text in the aspx mark up, right?  If so, you should not worry.  The client side editor will display the text you need, i.e.:

a >= b; & c