# Grid view Truncate Multiple Spaces (Works fine in Textbox)

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I have a gridview BoundField that need to display values present in a string as such- without applying HTML formaatting and preserving multiple white spaces in between (just like how the textboxes behave)

I tried the following approaches but didn't work. How can we make it work like the way textboxes do?

[image]

**MARKUP**

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:TextBox ID="Textbox1" runat="server" EnableViewState="false"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="Textbox2" runat="server" EnableViewState="false"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="Textbox3" runat="server" EnableViewState="false"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="Textbox4" runat="server" EnableViewState="false"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="B" DataFormatString="<pre>{0}</pre>"
            HtmlEncode="true" ItemStyle-BackColor="Gray" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="D" HtmlEncode="true" ItemStyle-BackColor="Cyan" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="E" ItemStyle-BackColor="Orange" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="C" HtmlEncode="false" ItemStyle-BackColor="Teal" />
         <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="A" DataFormatString="<pre>{0}</pre>"
            HtmlEncode="false" ItemStyle-BackColor="Yellow" />

    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
</form>
```

**C# CODE**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string selectedVal1 = "a    b";
    string selectedVal2 = "<br />";
    string selectedVal3 = "<script    1>";
    string selectedVal4 = "<script>";


    this.Textbox1.Text = selectedVal1;
    this.Textbox2.Text = selectedVal2;
    this.Textbox3.Text = selectedVal3;
    this.Textbox4.Text = selectedVal4;

    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    table.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
    table.Rows.Add(selectedVal1);
    table.Rows.Add(selectedVal2);
    table.Rows.Add(selectedVal3);
    table.Rows.Add(selectedVal4);

    GridView2.DataSource = table;
    GridView2.DataBind();

}
```

**HTML**

```
<input name="Textbox1" type="text" value="a    b" id="Textbox1" />
<input name="Textbox2" type="text" value="&lt;br />" id="Textbox2" />
<input name="Textbox3" type="text" value="&lt;script    1>" id="Textbox3" />
<input name="Textbox4" type="text" value="&lt;script>" id="Textbox4" />

<div>
<table cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" id="GridView2" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">B</th><th scope="col">D</th><th scope="col">E</th><th scope="col">C</th><th scope="col">A</th>
    </tr><tr>
        <td style="background-color:Gray;">&lt;pre&gt;a    b&lt;/pre&gt;</td><td style="background-color:Cyan;">a    b</td><td style="background-color:Orange;">a    b</td><td style="background-color:Teal;">a    b</td><td style="background-color:Yellow;"><pre>a    b</pre></td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td style="background-color:Gray;">&lt;pre&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;/pre&gt;</td><td style="background-color:Cyan;">&lt;br /&gt;</td><td style="background-color:Orange;">&lt;br /&gt;</td><td style="background-color:Teal;"><br /></td><td style="background-color:Yellow;"><pre><br /></pre></td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td style="background-color:Gray;">&lt;pre&gt;&lt;script    1&gt;&lt;/pre&gt;</td><td style="background-color:Cyan;">&lt;script    1&gt;</td><td style="background-color:Orange;">&lt;script    1&gt;</td><td style="background-color:Teal;"><script    1></td><td style="background-color:Yellow;"><pre><script    1></pre></td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td style="background-color:Gray;">&lt;pre&gt;&lt;script&gt;&lt;/pre&gt;</td><td style="background-color:Cyan;">&lt;script&gt;</td><td style="background-color:Orange;">&lt;script&gt;</td><td style="background-color:Teal;"><script></td><td style="background-color:Yellow;"><pre><script></pre></td>
    </tr>
</table>
 </div>
```

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/924058/asp-net-binding-to-gridview-strips-some-space-whitespace-characters

Comment: Reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/924058/asp-net-binding-to-gridview-strips-some-space-whitespace-characters and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6651739/how-to-disable-the-textboxs-html-encoding-in-asp-net and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6769138/response-write-print-text-from-database-as-html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the following C# code in RowDataBound event

```
e.Row.Cells[(int)logDescriptionIndex].Text = 
e.Row.Cells[(int)logDescriptionIndex].Text.Replace(" ", "&nbsp;");
```

Please note the following

1. Do not apply it on header row
2. Don not apply it on  table cells that has further formatting (for example Date Formatting) that can have spaces on formatting

Note: Following is based on another grid view; not for the gridview in question. Minor changes required to work with the gridview in question

**CODE**

```
    protected void SearchLogsGridRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e != null)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
            {
                if (logDescriptionIndex == null)
                {
                    int index = 0;
                    foreach (TableCell cell in e.Row.Cells)
                    {
                        if (cell.Controls[0] != null)
                        {
                            if (String.Equals(((LinkButton)(cell.Controls[0])).Text.Trim(), UIConstants.LogDescriptionHeader))
                            {
                                logDescriptionIndex = index;
                            }
                        }
                        index++;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                if (logDescriptionIndex != null)
                {
                    //  Replace white spaces with HTML space.
                    //  This is to handle multiple white spaces between two characters
                    e.Row.Cells[(int)logDescriptionIndex].Text = e.Row.Cells[(int)logDescriptionIndex].Text.Replace(" ", "&nbsp;");
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the exact Space in the Values then you must bound the fields on Gridview at the Design View...

Try like below..

```
DataFormatString="<pre>{0}</pre>"  // - this formating displays the values with spaces
```

Note that we are turning off the HTML Encoding in BoundField (`HtmlEncode="False"`) since we are using `pre` tag.

From [HTML pre Tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_pre.asp)

> Text in a pre element is displayed in a fixed-width font (usually Courier), and it preserves both spaces and line breaks.

From [BoundField.HtmlEncode Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.htmlencode.aspx)

> HTML-encoding field values helps to prevent cross-site scripting attacks and malicious content from being displayed. This property should be enabled whenever possible.

From [HttpServerUtility.HtmlEncode Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3te6wfz.aspx)

> If a text string contains a less than sign (<) or greater than sign (>), the browser would interpret these characters as the opening or closing bracket of an HTML tag. When the characters are HTML encoded, they are converted to the strings < and >, which causes the browser to display the less than sign and greater than sign correctly.

In design view setup the gridview like below..

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
<Columns>
<asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText ="Name" DataFormatString="<pre>{0}</pre>" 
HtmlEncode="False" />
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

In C# Code Behind (this is my Example... you can apply your own on this...)

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
table.Rows.Add( "Ab      Sdf");
GridView1.DataSource = table;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

and its output was like below...

[image: GridView OutPut]

Comment: This doesn't work when I put script 1 inside an open angle bracket and close angle bracket. Updated the question.

Comment: @Lijo : <script 1> is taken as HTML tag when you give HtmlEncode="false" so it does not work... Also i noticed that in Grid View Coloumn D and E you didn't give the attribut HtmlEncode="false" So they take them as Normal Text...

Answer (score 0):

By default, browsers remove consecutive spaces to leave only 1 in HTML text. If you wish to display all spaces, you'll need to have them replaced by the non-breaking space character "&nbsp" when displaying it in your gridview